# Detect WP7 Application is Idle and perform some task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a requirement where I have to detect if the user is not doing on Application and Application is idle(for certain period of time) and in the meantime, i.e while the application is idle before device screen gets locked, I have to show some images one by one.

I have gone through MSDN documentation of PhoneApplicationService.UserIdleDetectionMode and PhoneApplicationService.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode but i didn't found anything helpful.

How can i detect that application is idle ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HDWProduction's answer is along the lines of what I was thinking too. I don't think there is a way to know what the user has set the lockscreen timeout value to, so take that into consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detect that the application is NOT idle: Create a class containing a timer. When the timer fires, show the images. Whenever the user does ANYTHING on ANY page (detect this by e.g. overriding the manipulationstarted events), reset the timer to 0.